# Как настроить qt creator, что бы он использовал вместо стандартной командной стрик Windows terminal?

Tags: консоль, qtcreator

Скачал себе недавно windows termianl. Теперь у меня вопрос: как сделать так, что бы в qt creator он использовался вместо командной строки, и возможно ли это вообще?